# ¿Como borrar un item de un combobox en Tkinter Python?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Buenas Tardes Tengo en un programa de turnos un Combobox con las especialidades medicas, en un Tkcalendar la fecha y en otro Combobox los horarios. Mi pregunta es como puedo eliminar la hora especifica al reservar el turno eligiendo la especialidad, la fecha y el respectivo horario.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Por favor agrega lo que ya has intentado, revisa [ask].

Comment: Eliminaste la respuesta, no la pregunta. Hiciste bien, pero te quería avisar que no borraste la pregunta por las dudas.

Answer (score 1):

Asumiendo que cada horario es unico, puedes eliminar un item del combobox de esta forma:

```
from tkinter import ttk

combo = ttk.Combobox(values=("hola", "mundo","genial"))
combo.pack()

def eliminar_item(combo, item):
    # Obtenemos la tupla con los valores del combobox. La convertiremos a lista para que se pueda remover el item con el método remove.
    values = list(combo["values"])

    # Removemos de la lista values el primer item que coincida con item.
    values.remove(item)

    # Eliminamos los valores anteriores y establecemos los nuevos.
    combo["values"] = values

eliminar_item(combo, "mundo")
```